# How to modify SOAP response using java code?

Tags: java, soap, response

I have SOAP Request and also SOAP response in java code. In SOAP response I am getting `<return>` statement using java code.

I want to modify my SOAP response : Instead of `<return>` :::

I need it as

```
<userResponse> <userResponse> 
<userId> <userId> 
<image> <image>
```

can anybody help me out using java code to get the response for SOAP  or any useful link to get example.

Comment: Are you coding both the web service and the client that invokes the web service in this example?

Comment: I am developing only Server...and I have to make the response as client(Iphone,Android) needs it. please help me out , how should i generate the user defined response tags and display the result instead of <return> tag only.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but since you're coding the web service, can't you just modify the return string to be as you've indicated in your post?  Using JAX-WS [(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html), you can return a result string in an XML-formatted style and then the client can consume your return string as it needs to.

You could have multiple, separate methods to return individual components if you needed to as well (one method for the userResponse, one for the userId, etc...).

For example (a very simple one)...

```
package some_package_for_your_web_service;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class SomeClassForYourWebService {

    public void SomeClassForYourWebService() {}

    @WebMethod
    public String response() {
        return "<response>" +
                  "<userResponse>a_response</userResponse>" +
                  "<userId>a_user_id</userId>" +
                  "<image>an_image_url</image>" +
               "</response>";
    }
}
```